# Insert a comment above a selector in a nested media query in Sass

Tags: sass, media-queries, uncss

I'm using [UnCSS](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) with [Sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass). UnCSS removes unused CSS automatically; however, sometimes it removes things you don't want removed. You can include a comment above a rule like so:

```css
/* uncss:ignore */
.example { color: red; }
```

...to tell UnCSS to ignore that rule and include it in the final output.

I'm wondering how to include that comment in a nested media query in Sass:

SCSS:

```css
/* uncss:ignore */
.example {
  color: red;
  @media (min-width: 500px) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Output:

```css
/* uncss:ignore */
.example {
  color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .example {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```css
/* uncss:ignore */
.example {
  color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  /* uncss:ignore */
  .example {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Note the extra `/* uncss:ignore */` comment in the Desired Output example. Is it possible to do this in Sass?

Comment: Why would you expect Sass to insert more comments than you specified?

Comment: I don't expect Sass to insert more comments than what it does. I'm moreover looking for a way to do what's listed in "Desired Output" via Sass.

Comment: You're only writing the comment once in the provided code, so that's why you're only getting one comment in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. If it doesn't cause you difficulty you could re-write your SCSS to look like this:

```
/* uncss:ignore */
.example {
  color: red;
}


@media (min-width: 500) {
  /* uncss:ignore */
  .example {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```